# DDWRT synology nas no longer works

Tags: ssh, nas, synology, dd-wrt

I recently upgraded to DDWRT on my router, After doing so, I can't login to my Synology DS213's web interface (says cannot login as this account, root admin and my other admin account dont work) Also, the ssh keys I had setup that worked fine, no longer work.  I get

```
    ssh -vvv root@192.168.1.115
    OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
    debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/chs/.ssh/config
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.115 [192.168.1.115] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/chs/.ssh/identity type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/chs/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /c/Users/chs/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

And I cannot getinto the web interface to enable Telnet to even get in to check my config files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, my Synology NAS local IP changed from .115 to .135, also I needed to enable DDNS on DDWRT.  After doing so I was again able to SSH into my NAS with pubkey authentication as was already setup.